# How can a problem have complexity $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, time-complexity, matrix-product

For instance, it is believed that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an algorithm for matrix multiplication that runs in $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$, but possibly no algorithm that runs in $O(n^2)$. How is this possible? Couldn't we create a meta-algorithm that runs in $O(n^2)$ time by using a better and better algorithm to solve problems of bigger size?

Comment: There seem to be two questions here: (1) how can you have an algorithm for a problem with running time $n^{c+\epsilon}$ and (2) how can matrix multiplication admit such a method. Which one is it ?

Comment: I'm trying to ask (1). I've edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: There is a comparison-based sorting algorithm with complexity $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, but there is no such algorithm with complexity $O(n)$.

Comment: Still, that leaves a new question: are there problems for which no single asymptotically optimal algorithm exists?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2004/04/blum-complexity-measures.html

Comment: Usually that notation means that the constant hidden by the big-Oh notation depends on ε (and diverges as ε goes to zero).  Moreover, either the dependence is too complicated to solve for the best value of ε, or the author was too lazy to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's another way of saying that the algorithm runs in time $O(n^{2+o(1)})$; for example $O(n^2 \log^6 n)$ or $O(n^2 2^{\sqrt{\log n}})$ would both qualify.

Sometimes there are parameters other than the running time involved in an algorithm, for example quality of an approximation, that depend on $\epsilon$. In such cases, an algorithm may be designed to accept a parameter $\epsilon$ as a part of the input and adjust its performance accordingly.

Comment: This is *not* necessarily equivalent. Having a single algorithm in time $n^{2+o(1)}$ is a stronger condition than having infinitely many separate algorithms (which may not be computable) with running time $n^{2+\epsilon}$.